# jQuery: Missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('ready');
    $("#trigger").click(move() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
  });
  var move = function(){
    $('#box').css({
      'left': '0px',
      'transition': 'all 0.2s ease'
    })
  };
```

If I change the function in the .click from move() back to function() then it starts working again and the error disappears. Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Just started learning JS/jQuery to apologies if the answer is obvious.

Comment: `$("#trigger").click(WHAT?);`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `move() { ... }`?

Comment: So basically when the item is clicked, it applies the CSS effects to the element in my HTML. The element will come in off canvas and most to 0px on the page. Essentially a sidebar menu.

I thought if I put move() in there it would call my move() function and execute it?

Comment: You're missing a ) after the last bracket. `click` wants a function as an argument, what you're doing looks like a botched function declaration. change `move` to `function() {`

Comment: Thank you sir, that got it ^^^^

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuj4n2qt/)

I think you are trying to trigger the click on load and on click, it should call a function named `move()`. For that you'll hae to do it as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  $("#trigger").click(move());
});
var move = function() {
  alert('clicked');
  $('#box').css({
    'left': '0px',
    'transition': 'all 0.2s ease'
  })
};
```

**UPDATE**

As @Sterling and @Jack mentioned in their comments, change

```
$("#trigger").click(move());
```

to

```
$("#trigger").click(move);
```

as the earlier one triggers the click event as soon as the dom has been loaded. The final one will wait for the click event and then only fires the function.

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuj4n2qt/1/)

Comment: This is wrong -- `move()` triggers immediately. It's a function invokation. You want to remove the () and pass it as a function reference.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#trigger').click(move);`? Otherwise it'll call `move` immediately.

Comment: This has solved the issue I was getting thank you! However now it automatically executes the function instead of waiting for a click to occur?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thankyou.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#trigger").click(move(){
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Your problem is here. Specifically, `click(move()`. You are defining a function in here without the function keyword. If this is what you are attempting to do, replace '**move**' with '**function**' like so;

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Or create move as a separate function and then call it;

```
function move(){
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
}

$("#trigger").click(move);
```